# getting Apppath on Windows XP

Tags: java, windows

With the following Code I want to show my programm's location:

```
 String myPath =  getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
```

On Windows 7 it works perfectly, so I get the following result:

```
C:/Users/Admin/...
```

But my Problem is Windows XP. I get following URL:

```
C:/Dokumente%20und%20Einstellungen/Admin/...
```

How can I replace this `%20` in the code?!

This does not work: `myPath.replaceAll("%20"," ")`

Comment: *"I want to show my programm's location:"*  Why?  What application feature is this intended to support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myPath.replaceAll("%20"," ");
```

Does not edit `myPath` itself, it returns a string that you need to assign to your variable.

```
myPath = myPath.replaceAll("%20"," ");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JFileChooser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html) to find the directory.

```
String DefaultFolder=new JFileChooser().getFileSystemView().getDefaultDirectory().toString();
```